# PHP Strtotime erratic function

Tags: php, strtotime

The following code should take the fourth friday of February and the fourth friday of April and return it.

```
$datei1 = date(strtotime('fourth friday', strtotime('february', strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))));

$datei2 = date(strtotime('fourth friday', strtotime('april', strtotime(date('01-m-Y')))));
```

Its working but taking the 5th friday of April not the fourth. I can only assume that it does not believe the first of April counts.

Any ideas,

Marvellous

Comment: It's spelt "fourth", not "forth". Make sure it's spelt properly in your code. And those newlines probably don't help much.

Comment: Could you please state your OS distribution and PHP version

Comment: PHP says version 5 on the c_panel thats it

Comment: You can display the PHP version from PHP with `echo phpversion()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is very complicated for no reason. Try this (PHP 5.3):

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('fourth friday of april 2011'));
```

This will give you:

```
2011-04-22
```

In PHP 5.2, this syntax *seems* to work in all cases:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('fourth friday', strtotime('april - 1 second')));
```

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: It's a 5.3 syntax. OP didn't mention the version, so I assume he's using the latest.

Comment: Not working on our servers, but as a general point we don't want that as it should update itself automatically in 2012 2013 etc...

Comment: @Robin I expect the point was that you should generate "April 2011" from now() and then use that... Still, you appear to be using a PHP version prior to 5.3, so as @Tomalak has (psychically!) worked out, this won't work for you anyway.

Comment: You can instead use `strtotime('fourth friday of april this year')` instead which produce the correct output `strtotime('fourth friday of april')`

Comment: @Matt, @Tom on worked out that it won't work on his installation of php where as Matt and myself have "(psychically!) worked out" that this works for us. So without more information regard @Robin's installation you can't say for sure this won't work if executed correctly

Comment: @xzyfer I was basing my response on Robin saying "Not working on our servers..."

Comment: This is very similar to the end function of the current line and it is still returning the wrong date , strtotime(date('01-m-Y'))

Comment: @Matt, I've requested the OP post OS distro and PHP version for clarification

Comment: If I change it to the first friday it returns it as the 8th as well

Comment: @Robin Knight: Updated the answer with a PHP 5.2 solution, [which I tested for most cases and seems to work](http://codepad.org/MHI1FQc8).

Comment: @netcode, the OP specifically said the year should not be hard coded so you should update this `strtotime('april - 1 second')`, this automatically adjust for the current year

Comment: @xzyfer: "@Tom on worked out that it won't work on his installation of php" No, I noticed and demonstrated that it doesn't work on codepad.org's installation of php ([which is 5.2.5](http://codepad.org/about), btw).

Answer (score 2):

`strtotime('fourth friday', $now)` probably really means "the fourth Friday relative to `$now`".

The `$now` parameter you give is 1st April 2011, which is a Friday. The fourth Friday *after* Fri 1st April is the fifth Friday of the month.

Comment: Sounds right. If you want the fourth friday of April 2011, try `strtotime('fourth friday of April 2011');` :)

Comment: Could you expand on that, please? I tried it before I posted it, and it works for me. Is there something tricky going on?

Comment: Might be worth reading the changelog for strtotime (http://au2.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). There were major changes to how strtotime functions in php versions 5.0.2 and 5.2.7

Comment: What xzyfer said. Turns out that only works as of 5.3, and codepad.org runs 5.2.5. netcoder posted a great workaround for 5.2.*.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're using an older version of PHP. Major changes have been introduced to handle the edge case you're experiencing here. In which case I believe the following is the cleanest approach:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+4 fridays', mktime(0,0,0,4,0,date('Y'))));
// or
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('fourth friday', mktime(0,0,0,4,0,date('Y'))));
```

This should give you the fourth friday in april of the current year. I've tested successfully in 5.3 but you'll have to test on you older installation.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Changelog ::

5.2.7    In PHP 5 prior to 5.2.7, requesting a given occurrence of a given weekday in a month where that weekday was the first day of the month would incorrectly add one week to the returned timestamp. This has been corrected in 5.2.7 and later versions.

Comment: I already posted this in the comments. Can you do `echo phpinfo();` and tell us the exact version you are using

Comment: Done it PHP version 5.2.14 . I have just sent an email to the hosts to upgrade it. Is there another way of upgrading it?

Comment: 5.2.14 shouldn't have this issue though

Comment: It says in the changelog that this error was not corrected until. 5.2.7 . The exact problem is documented

Comment: Yes but 5.2.14 > 5.2.7 hence the issue should have been corrected by then.

Comment: quite. I missed a decimal place

Comment: is that to say you're running 5.2.1.4?