# php date subtraction using strtotime function not returning correct length of time

Tags: php, oracle, strtotime

I am converting PHP (v 5.2.17)-based reports to SSRS.

I'm trying to write a query that subtracts dates like the php file does.

The date calculation either matches exactly, or it differs by exactly 3600 seconds

```
  $timediff=strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))-strtotime("03/29/2007");
  print $timediff;  // 137635200 

  select (trunc(sysdate) - to_date('03/29/2007','MM/DD/YYYY'))*60*60*24 from dual
  -- returns 137635200 - matches


  $timediff=strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))-strtotime("11/23/2009");
  print $timediff;  // 53823600 

  select (trunc(sysdate) - to_date('11/23/2009','MM/DD/YYYY'))*60*60*24 from dual
  -- returns 53827200 - doesnt match - off by 3600
```

I've searched stackoverflow and found the following example which sounds like it (11/23/2009 is a monday, and so is today 8/8, but it doesnt differ in the same way) [PHP Strtotime erratic function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486949/php-strtotime-erratic-function)

My assumption is that the php calculation is wrong, and the oracle is correct.

What say you? ;-)

Thanks!

Comment: 3600 = an hour. Why would it be off by an hour? Maybe one is including daylight savings changes and one isn't?

Comment: Does the timezone on the PHP server match the timezone of the Oracle server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the exact values I suspect its because one of them is adjusting for daylight savings and the other is not. Most parts of the world change to/from  daylight savings time during march. So in your first example both dates are in the same GMT offset, but in the second (November) they're not.

So one of your platforms (probably Oracle) is taking this one hour shift into account and the other is not.

Comment: To find the PHP timezone, you can use `date_default_timezone_get()`. Some places in the world do not have daylight savings time and others do.

Answer (score 1):

3600 = an hour so could be timezone differences?

Answer (score 0):

53827200  = ( 623 * 60*60*24 )

So 53827200 is exactly 623 days of 24 hours.

53823600 is 622.958333 days or 622 days (of 24 hours) plus 23 hours.

Both are right, for a given definition of right.

Comment: Yes, but both calculations should result in the same amount of time.

Comment: Your question doesn't state how you want to accommodate longer/shorter days due to daylight savings. If/when you decide, then the PHP or the Oracle syntax can be adjusted to ask the correct question.